# How to get data from your internal gps with python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps

I've been working on a projects and I'm trying to use as minimal modules as I can (only basics like Numpy). I want to get accurate GPS data, I'm pretty sure that my computer has location service because I can turn int on in my settings. I know it possible if you use an arduino with gps shield and communicate with it over the serial connection but I would like to have just a script instead of a bunch of hardware.

**In Short**

I'm using python 3. How can I retrieve my location using a python script?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and consistent geocoding library written in Python.**

Many online providers such as Google & Bing have geocoding services, these providers do not include Python libraries and have different JSON responses between each other.

It can be very difficult sometimes to parse a particular geocoding provider since each one of them have their own JSON schema.

> **Geocode your own IP:**
>
> To retrieve your own IP address, simply have ‘’ or ‘me’ as the input.

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

output example:

```
[25.7333, 45.9667]
```

> Info: *https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/api.html*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the output I get is not very accurate. Is there a more accurate way to do it because now it's off by 2.42 Km (1.51 miles)

Comment: Hi! While this may answer the question (untested), it is SO best practice to include why this is a solution to OP's question. It helps OP better understand their problem and benefits future visitors to the site. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer. Thanks! --From Review

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

send_url = "http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=YOUR ACCESS KEY"
geo_req = requests.get(send_url)
geo_json = json.loads(geo_req.text)
latitude = geo_json['latitude']
longitude = geo_json['longitude']
city = geo_json['city']
```

Well this one works well but you need to get an access key from https://ipstack.com/
Which is free..just have to register!!

Answer (score -1):

you can use the google geolocation API for this!!

Comment: Is there any python documentation on that?

Comment: When creating my API I see that it isn't free, I'm sorry but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: have updated an answer above, the https://ipstack.com/ is the free one and you can experiment around but it has certain limitations, please go through the site for more info

Comment: Account also requires my address and other info I don't want to give away... thanks for you help!

Comment: Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: No problem!! do let me know if you get any alternate solutions!!